# Android - Download excel folder and store it to database

Tags: android, excel, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to download an excel file and store it into SQLite, i"ve been searching but couldn't find anything, thanks

Comment: `i"ve been searching but couldn't find anything` C'mon, you lazybone! Try doing some **real** search by yourself!! We ain't gonna google it for you and serve you the link on a silver plate.

Answer (score 0):

Storing binary files in SQLite database is [really bad idea](https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html). I should store Excel files in application (cache) directory and store filename to this file in SQLite only.

Anyway if you wants really store these files in SQLite you have to have BLOB column type.

Comment: Or maybe the OP means that s/he wants to convert an Excel file into a database table - That's how I understood that.

Comment: i just want to store data to the db, my idea is to download the file then import its data to the db but i think there is a better solution or a library